# How to implement chmod u-w in python

Tags: python, chmod

I know how to  implement chmod u+w with the following code:

```
st = os.stat(dest_file)
os.chmod(dest_file, st.st_mode | stat.S_IWUSR)
```

But how about u-w?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
st = os.stat(dest_file)
os.chmod(dest_file, st.st_mode & ~stat.S_IWUSR)
```

Explanation: `~` is the bitwise NOT operator, so a bitwise AND with `~stat.S_IWUSR` clears the flag from `st.st_mode`.

To illustrate with imaginary values:

```
stat.S_IWUSR                    00001000
~stat.S_IWUSR                   11110111
s.st_mode                       00101001
s.st_mode & ~stat.S_IWUSR       00100001
```